# About absolutely continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis

I read in some book that they have $f(x)=h(x)$ almost everywhere where $h$ is absolutely continuous 
and $f$ is in $L^2(0,1)$. Then he says that we may assume that $f(x)=h(x)$ for every $x$. Could you please explain this to me?

Thanks a lot.

Math

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is that the elements of $\ L^2(0,1)\ $ are not really *functions*, but *equivalence classes* of functions, each equivalence class comprising functions that differ from each other on at most a set of measure zero.  For two such functions $\ f_1, f_2\ $, we have $ \vert\vert f_1 - f_2 \vert\vert_{L^2(0,1)} =\sqrt{\int_0^1 \left\vert f_1(x) - f_2(x)\,\right\vert^2 dx} = 0\ $, so they must both represent the *same element* of $\ L^2(0,1)\ $.

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample: let

$h(x)=0$ for $x \in (0,1)$

and

$f(x)=0$, if $x \in (0,1) \setminus \{1/2\}$ and $f(1/2)=14.$

Comment: Thanks a lot Fred but why did Conway say that when he dealt with unbounded closed operators in his functional analysis book?

Comment: In fact, in Conway's book, he has $f(x)=-i\int_0^xg(t)dt$ a.e. where $g\in L^2(0,1)$ ($f$ is also in $L^2(0,1)$). Then, he says "we may assume that $f(x)=-i\int_0^xg(t)dt$ for all $x$".